# "Failed to execute aapt" after importing the admob unity package

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gradle, admob

After importing the admob unity package from here "https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/start", I could no longer build the project.

I tried restarting, different admob versions, resolving dependencies and a bit more I can't remember, but nothing had any affect.

I get the error underneath. (If the formatting is bad, here is the pastebin link "https://pastebin.com/ie48eGVa")

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed.
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\bin\java.exe -classpath "E:\Unity\2018.2.14f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-4.2.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m" "assembleRelease"

stderr[
C:\Users\bjell\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\androidx.browser.browser-1.0.0.aar\0ff9f681367b6a844235e6c9eb7fcb0b\res\values\values.xml:7:5-71: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.

C:\Users\bjell\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\androidx.browser.browser-1.0.0.aar\0ff9f681367b6a844235e6c9eb7fcb0b\res\values\values.xml:7:5-71: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.

E:\Unity\Project Trivia\Temp\gradleOut\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeReleaseResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:97: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
E:\Unity\Project Trivia\Temp\gradleOut\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeReleaseResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:97: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
error: failed linking references.

Failed to execute aapt
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:796)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.invokeAaptForSplit(ProcessAndroidResources.java:551)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.doFullTaskAction(ProcessAndroidResources.java:285)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor64.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:179)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:135)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:122)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:625)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:482)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:794)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:462)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.QueueableAapt2.lambda$makeValidatedPackage$1(QueueableAapt2.java:179)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.handleOutput(AaptProcess.java:463)
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.err(AaptProcess.java:415)
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$ProcessOutputFacade.err(AaptProcess.java:332)
    at com.android.utils.GrabProcessOutput$1.run(GrabProcessOutput.java:104)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processReleaseResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
]
stdout[
:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:Firebase:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:Firebase:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:Firebase:checkReleaseManifest
:Firebase:processReleaseManifest
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:checkReleaseManifest
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:processReleaseManifest
:preReleaseBuild
:Firebase:compileReleaseAidl
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:compileReleaseAidl
:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:Firebase:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:checkReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:Firebase:compileReleaseRenderscript
:Firebase:generateReleaseResValues
:Firebase:generateReleaseResources
:Firebase:packageReleaseResources
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:compileReleaseRenderscript
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:generateReleaseResValues
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:generateReleaseResources
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:packageReleaseResources
:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
:processReleaseManifest
E:\Unity\Project Trivia\Temp\gradleOut\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:24:9-31:50 Warning:
    activity#com.google.firebase.auth.internal.FederatedSignInActivity@android:launchMode was tagged at AndroidManifest.xml:24 to replace other declarations but no other declaration present
:splitsDiscoveryTaskRelease UP-TO-DATE
:Firebase:platformAttrExtractor
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:platformAttrExtractor
:Firebase:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:Firebase:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:Firebase:javaPreCompileRelease
:Firebase:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:javaPreCompileRelease
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
:compileReleaseNdk NO-SOURCE
:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
:compileReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:Firebase:mergeReleaseShaders
:Firebase:compileReleaseShaders
:Firebase:generateReleaseAssets
:Firebase:mergeReleaseAssets
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:mergeReleaseShaders
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:compileReleaseShaders
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:generateReleaseAssets
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:mergeReleaseAssets
:mergeReleaseAssets
:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:Firebase:compileReleaseNdk NO-SOURCE
:Firebase:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
:Firebase:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease
:Firebase:transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForRelease
:Firebase:transformNativeLibsWithIntermediateJniLibsForRelease
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:compileReleaseNdk NO-SOURCE
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForRelease
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:transformNativeLibsWithIntermediateJniLibsForRelease
:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
:validateSigningRelease
:Firebase:mergeReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:Firebase:transformNativeLibsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease
:Firebase:mergeReleaseResources
:Firebase:verifyReleaseResources
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:mergeReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:transformNativeLibsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:mergeReleaseResources
:Firebase:processReleaseResources
:Firebase:generateReleaseSources
:Firebase:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
:Firebase:transformClassesAndResourcesWithPrepareIntermediateJarsForRelease
:Firebase:extractReleaseAnnotations
:Firebase:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease
:Firebase:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease
:Firebase:bundleRelease
:Firebase:compileReleaseSources
:Firebase:assembleRelease
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:verifyReleaseResources
:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin:processReleaseResources
:processReleaseResources FAILED
67 actionable tasks: 51 executed, 16 up-to-date
]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1 progress, System.String error)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1 progress)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1 progress)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun()
```

Comment: I have the same problem, I'm using Ionic 3 and AdMob.